# Unable to upgrade laravel framework from 5.5 to 5.6 or 5.7 on an existing project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to upgrade my laravel project framework to 5.7 from 5.5 but unable to do it ..

when i change composerjson requres as laravel upgrading documentation and hit *composer update* on project terminal its output me these:

```
composer update
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - cartalyst/stripe-laravel v7.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.45], illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - cartalyst/stripe-laravel v7.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.45], illuminate/support[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.5.45].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - Installation request for cartalyst/stripe-laravel 7.0.* -> satisfiable by cartalyst/stripe-laravel[v7.0.0].
```

and this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "7.0.*",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^2.1.1",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0",
        "arcanedev/no-captcha": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "App\\Helpers\\": "app/Helpers/"
        },
        "files": ["app/Helpers/functions.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

tried many ways available on internet but still hanging on the problem

just want to upgrade the project laravel for new features ..

Anybody got any idea ? how can i solved this and go ahead with new laravel ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed PHP 7?

Comment: disable or remove all packages from composer.json file just keep laravel packages and than update later install all packages

Comment: You need at least PHP 7.1.3 to be able to use Laravel 5.6 and up.

Comment: @umefarooq  i tried your way .. got this out put at the last line of upgrading  Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
   and when run php artisan --version gor this error In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                   
  Class 'Spatie\Activitylog\ActivitylogServiceProvider' not found

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my system is running 7.3     bro

Comment: `cartalyst/stripe-laravel v7.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.5.*`. You need to use a newer version of that library since version 7.0.0 requires Laravel 5.5. (And please don't call me "bro").

Comment: @ffegu you need to commented all packages service provider in your app.php file.

Comment: @umefarooq   oo yeah it worked thank you you saved my day ..

Comment: @ffegu can i have created answer can you accept it.

Comment: @umefarooq yaeh sure thanks for help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Note:** Please check your PHP version first for laravel required version.

Best way to upgrade laravel framework for your projects in following steps

1. Take backup of your composer.json file
2. remove all third party packages from composer.json file or take latest composer.json from laravel git repository https://github.com/laravel/laravel
3. comment all third party packages service providers from app.php file (for version below Laravel 5.5)
4. Now run composer update command in terminal
5. Once Laravel update done. Now install all your third party packages again.
6. Better to install packages one by one you will able to find which package is not compatible with php version and laravel version.
7. Enable third party service provider on app.php file.

**update:**
if you are trying to upgrade laravel version 5.5 and up skip step 3. also for laravel 5.5 and up no need to enable third party package service providers in step 7.

Happy updating laravel for your projects.

Comment: I used this and it worked. Tried a lot of things before it that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install these packages first before run composer update, also change the version of laravel to 5.7 in your `composer.json` file.

**Ubundu Terminal Command**

```
sudo apt install php7.2 libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-soap php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip
```

- PHP >= 7.1.3
- Ctype PHP Extension
- JSON PHP Extension
- BCMath PHP Extension

> Delete the vendor folder and try `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

it was because of this line

cartalyst/stripe-laravel v7.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.5

thank you all for help...

i just update cartalyst packages and composer update its worked

conclusion : for update your laravel project remember to upgrade your 3rd party packages ..

Comment: thank you brother....i have old 3rd party package (not use anymore in my application)...after remove it, then i am able to upgrade laravel version..

Answer (score 0):

```
php -v
```

if below 7 , maybe you have alias like

```
php7 -v
```

or

```
php72 -v
```

many servers use php aliases

Answer (score -1):

just change the laravel to 5.7.* in composer.json file and run composer install command